# Distance between 2 coordinates in C# and google maps difference

Tags: c#, google-maps, spatial

I have harvested 2 coordinates `-2.232121, 53.477724` and `-2.231105, 53.478121` which are 80 metres apart according to Google maps.

I then convert these coordinates into .NET C# Spatial types like this..

```
var pointA = DbGeography.FromText("POINT (53.477724 -2.232121)", 4326);

var pointB = DbGeography.FromText("POINT (53.478121 -2.231105)", 4326);
```

When I calculate the distance between them, I get a totally different value.

```
var distanceAB = pointA.Distance(pointB);//distanceAb = 120.712849327128 metres
```

I need to know why these results are different, please.

Thanks.

Comment: Well a good question to start with is: which, if either, is correct?  Get out a pencil and paper and work out the spherical trigonometry and then at least you will know which is right.

Comment: How do you compute the Distance? Euclidian distance using the square root of the squared delta will _not_ do for geographic coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happened to me and I had lots of code and couldn't understand from where the bug comes and why (in my case the difference in distance was hundreds of kilometers) and after many efforts I have discovered the problem.

### The problem:

`POINT` first parameter is `Longitude` and the second is `Latitude` which is strange because all the methods receives as the first parameter `Latitude` and second `Longitude`.

e.g:

```
//First latitude then longitude.
public GeoCoordinate(double latitude, double longitude)
```

And POINT is opposite:

```
//First longitude then latitude.
String.Format("POINT ({0} {1})", location.Longitude, location.Latitude);
```

I don't know why it is opposite, but I know that here is a good spot for mistakes.

### The Solution:

Just to change the places of the coordinates:

```
var pointA = DbGeography.FromText("POINT (-2.232121 53.477724)", 4326);
var pointB = DbGeography.FromText("POINT (-2.231105 53.478121)", 4326);

var distanceAB = pointA.Distance(pointB); //distanceAB = 80.6382796064941 metres
```

OR a more readable syntax:

```
double longitudeA = -2.232121;
double latitudeA = 53.477724;

double longitudeB = -2.231105;
double latitudeB = 53.478121;

int coordinateSystemId = 4326;

var pointA = DbGeography.FromText(String.Format("POINT ({0} {1})", longitudeA, latitudeA), coordinateSystemId);
var pointB = DbGeography.FromText(String.Format("POINT ({0} {1})", longitudeB, latitudeB), coordinateSystemId);

var distanceAB = pointA.Distance(pointB); //distanceAB = 80.6382796064941 metres
```

Answer (score 2):

you have the latitude and longitude backwards: I get 80 meters between latitude: 53.477724, longitude: -2.232121 and latitude: 53.478121, longitude: -2.231105 = Distance:  0.08043 km; if I reverse the latitude/longitude, I get 0.1213 km (tested on [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html))

Comment: Oh gosh, I feel so stupid... Thanks and great answer